# Add editable text input to creditmemo totals

Tags: magento2, totals, creditmemo

[image: totals]

How to change the **-€5.00** simple text to a text input field (editable) ?

This is how I add the totals:

```
<?php
namespace My\Discount\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order;

class Totals extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
  public function initTotals()
  {
    $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();
    $order = $parentBlock->getOrder();
    $source = $parentBlock->getSource();

    $amount = $order->getData("discount_amount"); // custom field

    if (isset($amount)) {
      $total = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject([
        'code' => 'customdiscount',
        'value' => -$amount,
        'label' => "Custom Discount"
      ]);

      $parentBlock->addTotal($total, 'customdiscount');
    }

    return $this;
  }
}
```

> /view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_creditmemo_new.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="creditmemo_totals">
            <block class="My\Discount\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\Totals"
                   name="customdiscount" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using a block template in this way:

> view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_creditmemo_new.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="creditmemo_totals">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Creditmemo\NewMemo"
           name="customdiscount"
           template="Vendor_Module::creditmemo.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>

<move element="customdiscount" destination="creditmemo_totals" after="creditmemo_totals" />
```

> Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Creditmemo\NewMemo.php

```
public function initTotals() {
    $total = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject([
      'code' => 'customdiscount',
      'value' => 0,
      'label' => "Discount",
      'block_name' => 'customdiscount'
    ]);

    $this->getParentBlock()->addTotal($total, 'customdiscount');

    return $this;
}
```

In this way, the block total is overwritten with the template specified with `block_name`